# How to make VLC to start at various times when called more than once from command line?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I am able to start a video via VLC from the command line with the following command:

```
vlc videoName.mp4  --start-time=50 &
```

I want to start the same video at another position - without exiting that video/VLC.

To have this, I first have to set in `<Tool><Preferences>` the parameter "`Allow only one instance`" (otherwise another instance of VLC would be opened).

Unfortunately, executing

```
vlc videoName.mp4  --start-time=100 &
```

does not lead to any effect.

What would I have to do to (re)start the video at various positions once it is already running?

Comment: Copy the file to another name and start that one?

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, that is a good idea (though I have to see how I can set this into action with very big files). Unfortunately it presently does not work: vlc then starts videName-B.mp4 at the same position as videoName-A.mp4 was started :-(

Comment: If I understand right, you merely wish to reposition the video. Why use the command-line for that?

Comment: Yes, exactly; I want to reposition the video. I just mentioned the command line, as in the end I have to open the video  from a html file. In the html file certain hrefs exist that are assigned to various positions of the video.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this from VLC-0-9-x command-line help.

Usage: vlc [options] [stream] ...
You can specify multiple streams on the commandline. They will be enqueued in the playlist.
The first item specified will be played first.

Options-styles:

- --option  A global option that is set for the duration of the program.
- -option  A single letter version of a global --option.
- :option  An option that only applies to the stream directly before it
  and that overrides previous settings.

Looks like the "--" is a global option which is why it is the same between videos. If you want it specific to the video use ":"